# Set google chart width

Tags: css, grails, stylesheet, google-visualization

How can I set the width of the google chart api? I can resize it when i put it on a script tag, but I am using it this way to create a chart:

```
    <g:lineChart title='Sample Line Chart' titleAttrs="${['440000',30]}"colors="${colors}"axes="x,y" gridLines="10,10,1,0" type='xy' lineStyles="${[[3,6,3],[6,3,6],[6,6,7]]}" legend="${labels}" axesLabels="${[0['Jan','Feb','Mar'],1:[0,10,30,50]]}" fill="${'bg,s,efefef'}" dataType='text'data='${values5}' />
```

I tried putting a width='800px' but it doesnt work. Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Inline styles should be of the following format
`style="width:800px;"`

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I found a code snippet, and it works. Here it is:

```
    size="${[600,500]}"
```